# Filtering a character out of a string in C

Tags: c, string, filter, malloc

So below is a function that is supposed to filter out a given character, ch, from string, and put the filtered version in result.  The puts statement at the bottom ends up putting out a string identical to the original string, regardless of the filtered character, and result ends up being empty.

```
void filter_ch_index(char string[], char result[], char ch) {
    result[0] = NUL ; // placeholder
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        if(string[i] != ch)
        {
          result[i] = string[i];
        }
    }
    puts(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is your copying logic.

When the characters are different, you don't copy it into `result`, *but you increment `i` anyway*. That leaves **holes** in the `result` string. To solve that, you can use pointers (reference and increment).

Another problem I see is how you're calling the function. Do you allocate enough memory space for both?

I'll put a **very insecure** implementation of the function to show how you could do it. You should modify the function to account for string sizes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void filter(char *a, char *b, char c)
{
    char *aux = b;
    while(*a) {
        if(*a != c) *b++ = *a;
        a++;
    }
    *b = 0x0; // thx to @PaulRoub for pointing it out
    puts(aux);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[100];

    if(argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <string> <character>\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    filter(argv[1], buffer, argv[2][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, `aux` serves as a backup of the starting address of `b`. The `while` loop will go on while the current `a` character is not `\0` (you can read it as `while (*a != '\0')`). The condition is pretty straightforward too. The copying part is what I talked about earlier.

We **only increment the `b` string** if we copy something into it, otherwise, it's reference stays the same. The process will go on until the loop finds the `\0` terminating character in the `a` string.

The outputs:

```
[ ~/src/test ] $ ./filter "Stack Overflow Questions" e
Stack Ovrflow Qustions
[ ~/src/test ] $ ./filter "Stack Overflow Questions" S
tack Overflow Questions
[ ~/src/test ] $ ./filter "Stack Overflow Questions" s
Stack Overflow Quetion
[ ~/src/test ] $ ./filter "aaa bbb ccc abc cba" a     
 bbb ccc bc cb
[ ~/src/test ] $ ./filter "aaa bbb ccc abc cba" b
aaa  ccc ac ca
[ ~/src/test ] $ ./filter "aaa bbb ccc abc cba" c
aaa bbb  ab ba
[ ~/src/test ] $
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two indexes, the one you're reading from and the one you're writing to:

```
void filter_ch_index(char string[], char result[], char ch)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (string[i] != ch)
            result[j++] = string[i];
    }
    result[j] = '\0'
    puts(result);
}
```

This assumes that `result` is big enough.  Note that the most common order for arguments in copying functions is 'destination, source' (see `strcpy()`, `memmove()`, …), but you have the order reversed.

Note that using the original `for(i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)` is a bad idea.  Using `strlen()` in the loop condition like that converts a linear algorithm into a quadratic algorithm unless you've got a sophisticated enough compiler to spot that the length of the string doesn't change on each iteration of the loop.  (War story: once upon another millennium, there was an implementation of `strstr()` that included a loop condition like that.  It worked fine on small strings — say under 100 bytes; it was a disaster when used on strings of 20 KiB and more.  Most platforms were fine — this one was not.  The bug has long since been fixed.)

Note that you could modify the source string in situ safely; the output string is never longer than the source string. This avoids buffer overflows unless the source string is itself invalid (not null terminated).  `void replace_ch(char *string, char ch)` is the interface.  The function above could be written with `void filter_ch_index(const char string[], char result[], char ch)` with the `const` indicating that the source string will not be modified by the function.